# How to trigger YAML file from previous stage using cache and trigger in gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration

I have two jobs where ine job creates YAML files in project respective folder and other job   utilizes the cached YAML files and trigger the job. In the below scenario the `child_pipeline` is not triggering the YAML. Please advise how to trigger all the YAMLs present in the directory.

```html
variables:
  yamlPath: ''

# stages:
#   - build
#   - test

generateyaml:
  stage: build

  image:
    name: amazon/aws-cli
    entrypoint: ['']

  before_script:
    - yum -y install zip
    - /bin/yum -y install jq
    - yum -y install git

  script:
    - echo $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE
    - cp deployment_scripts/deploy.sh .
    - rm -rf deployment_scripts
    - bash deploy.sh
    - yamlPath=$(echo $(ls -aR | grep .yml | sed "s|.gitlab-ci.yml||g" | xargs echo | sed 's/ /,/g'))
    - echo $yamlPath

  # artifacts:
  #   paths:
  #     - build/

  cache:
    # key: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG-$CI_JOB_NAME'
    key: $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
    untracked: true
    paths:
      - '*.yml'
    when: 'always'

# stages:
#     - include
#     - deploy

child-pipeline:
  script:
    - ls -aR
  cache:
    key: $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
    paths:
      - '*.yml'
    policy: pull

  trigger:
    include: '*.yml'
```

Currently I am getting YAML error

```
jobs:child-pipeline config contains unknown keys: trigger
```

Comment: The syntax looks ok to me out of the include which should spevify local before. But I think you want a dynamic pipeline and you should follow this part of the doc: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/downstream_pipelines.html#trigger-a-dynamic-child-pipeline

Comment: You also can't have both a `trigger` and a `script` on the same job; you'll want to likely remove your `ls -aR` from the child-pipeline job

Comment: @Tensibai Can we use cache to pull the YMLs. BEcause we need them to sit in specific folder and run from the same path. Please advise.